# How to reindex a python array to move polyline starting point?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python array defining the points for a polyline P(x,y,z). I need to align the points with points on another polyline - to be precise, the point with index 0 on polyline 1 should be close to the point with index 0 of the second polyline.

Think of a polyline circle. How can I move the "index number" or rather rearrange the points in an array so that the index number of the points moves clockwise or counter clockwise by x points?

Klausb

Comment: do you mean shifting a list like: `[1,2,3] --> [2,3,1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

To shift to left by x points(assuming x is less than the length of array):

```
newPolyline = polyline[x:] + polyline[:x]
```

To shift right:

```
newPolyline = polyline[len(polyline) - x:] + polyline[:len(polyline) - x]
```